# Calcular a diferença de horas úteis entre duas datas

Tags: php

Preciso calcular a diferença de horas úteis entre duas datas

ex:

```
$dataIni = '201705151330';
$dataFim = '201705161230';
```

Até ai consigo resolver com o seguinte código:

```
$dataIni = '201705151330';
$dataFim = '201705161230';  

$datatime1 = new DateTime($dataIni);
$datatime2 = new DateTime($dataFim);


$data1  = $datatime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data2  = $datatime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  

$data1 = strtotime($data1);
$data2 = strtotime($data2);

$nHoras   = ($data2 - $data1) / 3600;
$nMinutos = (($data2 - $data1) % 3600) / 60;
$total = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras , $nMinutos);

echo $total;
```

Mas preciso levar em consideração que o turno é das **07:30** até as **12:00** 
e das **13:30** até as **17:48**, ou seja preciso descontar o horário de almoço e as horas não trabalhadas. Como posso resolver isso em PHP?

Comment: Então mostre o que já fez

Comment: Como pode um evento começar as 13:30 e terminar as 12:30 do mesmo dia? Por favor, entre em [edit] e adicione qual é o seu código até agora, como indicado no comentário acima, e adicione um [mcve], isto é, valores de início e fim que fazem sentido, assim como o resultado esperado quando a entrada for estes valores.

Comment: Ok, inclui o meu código e corrigi os períodos do exemplo.

Comment: Antes vc tinha colocado as datas do mesmo dia, o que dava a entender que vc tinha se enganado quanto a $dataIni e $dataFim o que me induziu a esse script.

Comment: Sim, antes estava errado conforme citado pelo @anderson-carlos-woss porém alterei logo em seguida.

Comment: e a $dataIni e $dataFim podem ser quaisquer horários e quaisquer dias?

Comment: Sim, podem ser em horários e dias diferentes, a aplicação que estou desenvolvendo tem a finalidade de levantar a quantidade de horas úteis que uma maquina ficou parada em razão de manutenção.

Comment: Esse é um problema mais de lógica de que PHP.
O que você precisa é mudar a forma como voce está resolvendo o problema.
Existe um período mínimo de 8 horas que o cara tem que trabalhar. 
O que você precisa entender agora são os extras, que acontecem quando o cara entra ANTES dá 7:30 e sai DEPOIS das 17:48
Basicamente, Hras = 8 + (hraEntrada - 7:30) + (17:48 - hraSaida)

Comment: Já consegui resolver, obrigado. Só não vou postar o código por que ficou muito extenso.

Comment: muito legal isso, se alguém tivesse resolvido seu problema e não postasse por ser muito extenso acho q vc não iria ficar curioso não né, alias o meu não ficou tão extenso, mas vc já teve sua solução e isso basta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode solucionar este problema fazendo uso das classes nativas que o PHP oferece para manipular [Data/Hora](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

De acordo com a descrição do seu problema uma possível solução seria calcular o número de minutos entre duas datas onde deve considerar somente o período que se encontra entre os turnos definidos:

```
<?php

$dataIni = '201705151330';
$dataFim = '201705161230';

$datatime1 = new DateTime($dataIni);
$datatime2 = new DateTime($dataFim);

$intervaloEmMinuto = new DateInterval('PT1M');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($datatime1, $intervaloEmMinuto, $datatime2);
$minutos = 0;
foreach ($periodo as $data) {
        /* @var $data \DateTime */
        $dataEmMinuto = clone $data;

        $inicioDoPrimeiroTurno = clone $dataEmMinuto->setTime(7, 30, 0);
        $fimDoPrimeiroTurno = clone $dataEmMinuto->setTime(12, 0, 0);
        $inicioDoSegundoTurno = clone $dataEmMinuto->setTime(13, 30, 0);
        $fimDoSegundoTurno = clone $dataEmMinuto->setTime(17, 48, 0);

        if (($inicioDoPrimeiroTurno < $data && $data < $fimDoPrimeiroTurno) || ($inicioDoSegundoTurno < $data && $data < $fimDoSegundoTurno)) {
                $minutos++;
        }
}

$intervalo = new DateInterval("PT{$minutos}M");
$data = new DateTime();
$dataAtual = clone $data;
$data->add($intervalo);
$horasUteisEntreDuasDatas = $dataAtual->diff($data);
echo 'Horas úteis entre duas datas: '. $horasUteisEntreDuasDatas->format('%d dias %H horas %i minutos');
```

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar esse código, estava a um bom tempo com a mesma dúvida à cima e seu código funcionou perfeitamente calculando as horas úteis.